# How can I reset the Windows 8.1 hints and tips?

Tags: windows-8.1

I was setting up a new PC for an older person who is not comfortable using computers, and Windows wasted the popup hints on me about what the corners do.

There's a good deal of information in the Help+Tips app that has the same demonstrations but the presentation may be a little too abstract for him.

I think it would really help if I could reset these tips. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try making a new user account for him and let him be the first to log into it?

Comment: @techie007 We used his LiveID for default account.

Comment: Ok, make a new user, delete the original user and make it again as a "new" account.  Also look into perhaps using "Sysprep /oobe" to reset it to the "Out Of Box Experience"?  Or perhaps using Window 8.1's in-built Refresh/Reset features?

Comment: @techie007 Haven't tried any of those, but thanks they sound like good suggestions. I'll look into them.

Comment: No problem.  check them out, and if you try them come back with results (if it doesn't help add your results to your question), if it fixes it, go ahead and post exactly what you did as an answer to your own question (it's allowed ;) )